# The result of subscribe is not used on rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

Hello I want ask about rxJava and Room.

here is Dao for my Room:

```
@Query("SELECT * from `Order` WHERE id = :ID")
fun findOrderById(ID: Int): Flowable<Order>
```

here is the code to call Dao:

```
 mDB.orderDataDao().findOrderById(orderId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe {
                    if (it.deliveryStatus == EnumOrder.IN_DELIVERY.name) {
                        mView.orderInProgress()
                        mView.setOrderFromDB(it, true)
                    } else {
                        mView.noOrderInProgress()
                        mView.setOrderFromDB(it, false)
                    }
                }
```

my question is why I got warning "The result of subscribe is not used on rxjava" when call Dao. why this happen and how I can make this right? I got that's warning in every code use rxJava.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`subscribe()` should return a [`Disposable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/Disposable.html), which you can use to unregister your interest in receiving updates from your `Flowable` at a later point. To remove this warning, store the Disposable returned from subscribe in an instance variable, and use it with lifecycles to unsubscribe from updates. e.g.:

```
val disposable = mDB.orderDataDao().findOrderById(orderId).subscribe { /**/ }

//...

disposable.dispose();
```

Comment: so after update done I must call `disposable.dispose();`
or I just call `disposable.dispose();` when activity stop or destroy?

Comment: That's right - call `dispose()` whenever you're no longer interested in receiving updates. This will usually be in a life-cycle call back like `onStop` or `onDestroy`

Answer (score 3):

Or create `CompositeDisposable` in your presenter and add each disposable there. And in `onDestroy()` call `compositeDisposable.dispose()`.